# Second Firebase Auth Overwrites First

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase project with two databases, A and B.

I am signing into both databases with JavaScript, each from a separate Google Chrome tab, with unique credentials. Tab 1 signs into database A with custom token X. Then, Tab 2 signs into database B with custom token Y.

Oddly, after Tab 2 signs in, Tab 1 becomes the same user as Tab 2, and gets permission denied errors on database A.

Why is this happening and how can I accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was the [Authentication State Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) conflicting between the two tabs; the second tab would overwrite the browser session of the first tab.

In-memory persistence was what I needed:

```js
import { getAuth, inMemoryPersistence, signInWithCustomToken } from "firebase/auth";
...
const auth = getAuth(app);
auth.setPersistence(inMemoryPersistence);

signInWithCustomToken(auth, token)
...
```